# Denying DDL & DML Privileges Based On HostName

Tags: sql-server, permissions

Developers must not use DML and DDL commands in my company. So, I revoked their authority like update, delete, or drop commands. But, they are able to alter or update some stored procedures or records by using our application user credentials from their applications.

Can I block the users based on their hostname not to execute update, delete, alter, or drop commands in SQL Server?

Comment: The hostname can be spoofed. The underlying issue that the devs have access to the app credentials. To fix that, your organization needs segregation of duties.

Comment: But this is not in my hand. Is not there anything that i can do out of it? By the way, how can hostname be spoofed? Is this possible?

Comment: The application can specify any hostname in the connection string, which is returned by the `HOST_NAME()` function and DMVs. Other than protecting secrets from unauthorized users, you could use network security to allow access to the database server by only authorized hosts.

Comment: How is this out of your hand? Change the passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Why would the application run-time credentials need to CREATE or ALTER stored procedures? REVOKE that from those credentials and GRANT only EXECUTE privileges.

Have a different credential (maybe a production DBA?) deploy changed code during releases.